# Android battery consuption

Tags: android, power-management

3rd party is running battery test on my android app.
They say that "Exceeds idle mode current when there is no services running with no data connectivity" for the test

test : Idle screen power after quiting the application

Current consumed (mA) :108.93

Battery Life time (hrs) : 11.11

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You require additional pylons...but seriously. You have not provided us with enough information to help.

Comment: which 3rd party app are you using for the test?

Comment: if they quit you application - your application is not using any power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing lot of database inserts into sqlite. But it was one time thing at the time of first run.